# How can I use in customRanking of scout-extended enum field?

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

On laravel site with algolia/scout-extended I have next description in config file on customRanking:

> /*
> |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Custom Ranking
> |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Custom Ranking is about leveraging business metrics to effectively
> rank search | results - it's crucial for any successful search
> experience. Make sure that | only "numeric" attributes are used, such
> as the number of sales or views. | | Supported: Null, Array |
> Examples: ['desc(comments_count)', 'desc(views_count)'] |
> */
>
> 'customRanking' => ['desc(completed_at)', 'desc(created_at)'],

I need to use for field with enum field which use integer values actually:

```
enum('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Can I use this enum field for customRanking and which condition must be used ?
I prefer not to change type of the field, as I have data on the app...

```
"algolia/scout-extended": "^3.0",
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
```

Thanks in advance!